# Sorting a dictionary (with date keys) in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary. The keys are dates (datetime). I need to sort the dictionary so that the values in the dictionary are sorted by date - so that by iterating through the dictionary, I am processing items in the desired chronological (i.e. date/time) order.

How may I sort such a dictionary by date?

Example:

```
mydict = { '2000-01-01': {fld_1: 1, fld_2: 42}, '2000-01-02': {fld_1:23, fld_2: 22.17} }
```

Note: I am using strings here instead of datetime, to keep the example simple

Comment: sorting should work in yyyy-mm-dd format as strings also.

Comment: Glad someone already asked this ;)

Answer (score 22):

If you're using Python 2.7+ or 3.1+ you could create an [`OrderedDict` from `collections`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from a sort of your dictionary and then iterate through that.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

ordered = OrderedDict(sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

However, depending on what you want to do it's probably easier to iterate over a sorted list of keys from your dict.

Comment: What might be even better than creating an `OrderedDict` or retrieving and then sorting the keys after any changes are made to the dictionary, would be a [SortedDict](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sorteddict).

Comment: Why do people persist in using `key` when they just want the natural sort order?

Comment: For Python newbies like me, @martineau meant that you can accomplish the same goal like this
`ordered = OrderedDict(sorted(mydict.items())`

Note that the sort works the same if the keys are actual datetime objects and not strings

Comment: @jbustamovej: I literally meant download, install, and use the [`sorteddict`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sorteddict) extension module instead of what's in this answer (or the alternative in your comment). "The main benefit of `sorteddict`s is that you never have to explicitly sort."

Comment: It saved my day. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Dictionaries are unsortable. Iterate over `sorted(mydict.keys())` instead.

Comment: it is possible also say `sorted(mydict)` if you prefer.

Answer (score 5):

Dictionaries never store anything in some order. But you can get a list of keys using `d.keys()` which could be sorted. Iterate over a generator like below.

```
def sortdict(d):
    for key in sorted(d): yield d[key]
```

Using this you will be able to iterate over values in chronological order.

```
for value in sortdict(mydict):
    # your code
    pass
```

Comment: you don't need `.keys()` there

Comment: @SilentGhost: oh yeah! there you go.

Answer (score 2):

since your date strings seem to be in a proper format you could just do:

```
>>> sorted(mydict.items())         # iteritems in py2k
[('2000-01-01', {'fld_2': 42, 'fld_1': 1}), ('2000-01-02', {'fld_2': 22.17, 'fld_1': 23})]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that python knows how to compare dates. So:

```
def sortedDictValues(adict):
 items = adict.items()
 items.sort()
 return [value for key, value in items]
```

Comment: Python compares `datetime` objects without any problems. In this case `YYYY-MM-DD` strings are also correctly comparable. A problem would be date in format `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD.MM.YYYY`, but not with `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: The last three lines of your code can be also written as `return [value for key, value in sorted(adict.items())]`

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 (released on July 3rd, 2010) supports an ordered dictionary type:

http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/

Comment: ordered dictionary remembers the order of insertion. But blist module has sorteddict http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/

Comment: but doesn't the order dictionary also have a "sort" function?

Comment: If you put it that way, yes. And then it would stay for future use. More natural for me would be to sorteddict.