# Sort a dict with date key in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dict with date time key as bellow

```
{u'2014-04-21 14:46': {u'status': 0, u'created': u'21-04-2014 14:46', u'duration': u'0:12'}, u'2014-04-22 10:31': {u'status': 0, u'created': u'22-04-2014 10:31', u'duration': u'1:28}}
```

I need to sort that with date time key.

I have already tried as below which is mention in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977310/sorting-a-dictionary-with-date-keys-in-python) and it is not sorting as expected.

```
ordered = OrderedDict(sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

In that question key is `2014-04-21` and mine is `2014-04-21 14:46`.

Any help would appreciate.

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: how to sort a dict with date key in python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see from your sample set, you are using ISO dates.

ISO dates are [alphabetically sortable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). There is no need to handle the special case of them being dates. I see nothing wrong with your code.

Running your code, e.g.

```
>>> list(OrderedDict(sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0])))
```

produces the keys sorted, e.g.

```
[u'2014-04-21 14:46', u'2014-04-22 10:31']
```

To sort the list in *decending* order, use

```
>>> list(OrderedDict(sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0], reversed=True)))
```

Comment: But it is not sorting

Comment: Then I am misunderstanding your expectations. I ran your code, and it met what I expected.

Comment: try to reverse it and check the result

Comment: `list(OrderedDict(sorted(reversed(mydict.items()), key=lambda t: t[0])))` still produces what I expect. Did I misunderstand what you intended somehow?

Comment: Ah, I think you want to sort the dates decending, right? Check the `reversed` parameter to `sorted`.

Comment: thanks, this is working fine.
`OrderedDict(sorted(repo.items(), key=lambda t: t[0],reverse=True))`

Comment: The `key` parameter is not needed. Sorting uses the first element by default anyway.