# How can i sort python dictionary by time in descending order

Tags: python, sorting, date, dictionary, time

I have to sort dictionary in which key is in date-time format, I have to sort the dictionary by date time descending order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting a dictionary (with date keys) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977310/sorting-a-dictionary-with-date-keys-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to sort dictionary in Python:
You can use sorted method for list of keys:

```
for key in sorted(mydict):
     print "%s: %s" % (key, mydict[key])
```

Or you can use (I think that's a better way)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
```

Check out the usage here https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes